# How to point GoDaddy to EntryDNS domain

Tags: dns, godaddy

I have a server connected via dynamic IP. I have set up EntryDNS to manage the change of my IP. If I put in my EntryDNS URL it points me to my server's current IP. I purchased a domain from GoDaddy, but I have been unable to get it to point to my EntryDNS.

What I want is to be able to ssh to my server, but ideally I'd like to do this by using my domain name. I must confess I'm a bit overwhelmed by the GoDaddy interface. So the bottom line is, how do I point my GoDaddy domain to my DNS domain so that when I look up the domain I get the current IP of the server?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://entrydns.net/pages/help it says the below are your name servers.

```
ns1.entrydns.net
ns2.entrydns.net
ns3.entrydns.net
```

In GoDaddy to edit your name servers follow these instructions.
[To Set Nameservers for a Domain Name Registered with Us](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/668/registering-your-own-nameservershosts)